# How to pass a template to a function as a paramater

Tags: c++, oop

```
    // Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

int returnSize(template z <class T, size_t>)
{
    /*if(arr.size() ==0)
    return 1;
    else
    return 2;
    */
    return 1;
}

int main()
{

  array<int,5> z;

  cout<<returnSize(z)<<endl;
}
```

I am trying to pass this array template z to a function so I can calculate its size.But, I am clueless on how to pass the template as a parameter to a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't declare the template itself inside the function's parameters.  The template needs to be in front of the function, and then you can use the template parameters inside the function as needed, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template <class T, size_t N>
int returnSize(const std::array<T, N> &arr)
{
    return arr.size();
    // or: return N;
}

int main()
{
    std::array<int,5> z;
    std::cout << returnSize(z) << std::endl; // <-- calls returnSize<int,5>(z) ...
}
```

Output:

> 5

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/w6xjAl)

Comment: Didn't your favorite compiler warn you about mixing up `size_t` and `int` ?

Comment: @rustyx I used the compiler in the demo link I provided.  So, no, it did not.